# Duplicate stderr in unix, ksh specifically

Tags: logging, duplicates, ksh, stderr

I am writing ksh scripts.
Since I can not control job scheduler or access its logs, I am logging:

```
exec 2>>logfile  1>&2
```

at the start of the file and using  to log:

```
echo "good job"
```

To quickly check logfiles for errors how can I duplicate stderr to logfile and an error file?
I imagine something with new file descriptors or tee or tty?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want stderr to end up in the logfile (along with stdout) and just stderr to end up in the errorfile?

Comment: Are you still interested in a solution?

Answer (score 1):

By doing:

```
echo "good job" | tee errorlog
```

You'll echo to the script default output (log file I suppose), and the message will be duplicated to "errorlog" as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every time you try to re-use the standard file descriptors like :

```
<cmd> 1>err 2>>err 1>out
```

It rewrites the definition of the first definition.That is, 1 is now only pointing to out and 2 to err. Your best bet would be to use two separate files (like err and out) and timestamping the outputs and sorting it yourself to get the combined output.